# MySQL syntax for conditional CONCAT depending on a field content?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, conditional-statements, concatenation

I have inherited a simple table from a client, that stores two addresses (shipping address and business address) in just two fields shipping_address and business_address. There is a field called ship_to with enum('shipping','business'), and a field for a full name. The client wants an output as:

full name: address

Where "address" column should be picked by the ship_to value. If ship_to = shipping then use shipping_address column. If ship_to = business then use business_address column.

For instance:

```
Joe Smith: Roach Street #10, Rats Village
```

How I can use CONCAT with IF condition? I'm **guessing** something like this, which obviusly is just an idea:

```
SELECT CONCAT( full_name, ':', IF (ship_to=='shipping', shipping_address, business_address ) AS contact FROM `table`
```

But, what's the right syntax for doing this?

Comment: you are missing a closing `)` and also in SQL compare is done with a single `=` not `==`

Comment: I just tried but only works if I prefix the fields, that's it, if I specify table.full_name, table.ship_to, table.shipping_address and table.business_name...I wonder if that's really needed or it is a kind of server issue? It doesn't work at all without the table.

Comment: @AramAlvarez What sort of error produced, if table name prefix not specified?

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'shipping_address' in 'field list'

Comment: very confusing situation.  Did you tried `CASE` rather than `IF`? also Did you run query in mysql console?

Comment: well, I left it working with the table prefix, however it works as it should without the table prefix in the console...it just doesn't work without it inside the PHP script, neither in the PHPMyAdmin SQL query box. And this is hosted in Hostgator...

Answer (score 2):

Lacking the closing `)`

```
SELECT 
CONCAT( full_name, ':', IF (ship_to='shipping', shipping_address, business_address )) as    contact
FROM TableName
```